# Multimedia timer? <mmsystem.h>

Tags: c++, windows, linker

I'm trying to get this accurate timer working on VS2008, on Windows XP (and eventually Server 2008) from the following example:

http://technology.chtsai.org/w98timer/

However I get the following errors:

- error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_timeEndPeriod@4
- error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_timeGetTime@0
- error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_timeBeginPeriod@4
- error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_timeGetDevCaps@8

Could anybody please advise?

I just want a simple, accurate, millisecond-timing example for C++ on Windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

void 
main (void)
{
  TIMECAPS resolution;
  DWORD start, finish, duration, i;

  if (timeGetDevCaps (&resolution, sizeof (TIMECAPS)) == TIMERR_NOERROR)
    {
      printf ("Minimum supported resolution = %d\n", resolution.wPeriodMin);
      printf ("Maximum supported resolution = %d\n", resolution.wPeriodMax);
    }

  if (resolution.wPeriodMin <= 1)
    {
      if (timeBeginPeriod (1) == TIMERR_NOERROR)
    {
      for (i = 100; i <= 120; i++)
        {
          start = timeGetTime ();
          while (timeGetTime () < (start + i));
          finish = timeGetTime ();
          duration = finish - start;
          printf ("expected:%d  actual:%ld\n", i, duration);
        }
      timeEndPeriod (1);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [MSDN suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need to include `winmm.lib` into the project. So add the following line anywhere into your source code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it looks like you need to add `Winmm.lib` to the additional libraries to link in your project properties.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `winmm.lib` to your linker dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

These functions are defined in winmm.dll.  You need to add winmm.lib to your link list.